# pry-rails not rails console working with Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pry

included 'pry-rails' in my Gemfile run console and get the following

```
@marketplace-rails/gems/pry-rails-0.2.0/lib/pry-rails/commands.rb:3:in `block in <module:PryRails>': undefined method `create_command' for #<Pry::CommandSet:0x007fcfaa67a878> (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Step 1. don't use 'pry-rails' ? (not sure how to get that gem
  working)
- Step 2. in gemfile include `gem 'pry'`
- Step 3. in application.rb include the following...

> ```
> console do
>   require "pry"
>   config.console = Pry
> end
> ```

run rails console be happy to have pry back in your life.

Answer (score 7):

For what it's worth, I just tried this:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-rails'
end
```

Followed by a bundle install and a 'rails c' and pry came up.

Answer (score 3):

Try stopping spring,

```
$ bin/spring stop
```

worked for me after installing the gem, didn't even have to change it in the config/environment/development file either

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have pry included in your Gemfile and add

```
config.console = Pry
```

to your config/environments/development.rb or to your config/application.rb if you want it in every environment.